# TouchableHighlight underlayColor not working. The color just does not change

Tags: javascript, react-native, touchablehighlight

I have a component with this:

```
<TouchableHighlight
    style={styles.button}
    underlayColor='red'
    onPress={() => this.bootEvent(item)}>
    <Text style={{ color: '#ffffff', fontSize: 12, fontWeight: 'bold' }}>Text</Text>
</TouchableHighlight>
```

This is the style:

```
button: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#4267b2',
    padding: 8
}
```

The problem is that when I click on the button, the onPress function is called but the color of the TouchableHighlight remains the same.

I also tried with this:

```
underlayColor={'red'}
```

with brackets, but its the same.

Comment: It is working as expected, when you *click and hold* the `onPress` button the underlay color will change to red

Comment: you right Pritish Vaidya.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In case anyone comes across this behaviour, `onPress` needs to be supplied in order to see the colour change or highlight effect working. See https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/14908